# Oracle Query with null values

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is the requirement, can you help me to get desired query..

```
create table sales(Order_ID number, item varchar2(20));

insert into sales values (10, 'RICE');
insert into sales values (10, 'WATER');
insert into sales values (10, 'SALT');
insert into sales values (20, 'TOMATO');
insert into sales values (20, 'ONION');
insert into sales values (30, 'OIL');
insert into sales values (30, 'EGG');
insert into sales values (40, 'CHICKEN');
insert into sales values (50, 'FISH');
```

I need output as below format.

```
Order_ID    ITEM
10          RICE
            WATER
            SALT
20          TOMATO
            ONION
30          OIL
            EGG
40          CHICKEN
50          FISH
```

Comment: Is this on MySQL or Oracle database? Also, what determines the order in which the items get displayed within each order_id?

Comment: It is needed in oracle database. order can be anything. no need of specific order.

Comment: If it's an Oracle db, please don't tag the question as MySQL as well.

Comment: You forgot to tag other **RDBMS** products like `sql server`, `postgresql`, `db2` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `row_number()` analytic function plus a case statement in order to only populate the order_id for the first row:

```
select case when rn = 1 then order_id end order_id,
       item
from   (select order_id,
               item,
               row_number() over (partition by order_id order by item) rn
        from   sales);

  ORDER_ID ITEM                
---------- --------------------
        10 RICE                
           SALT                
           WATER               
        20 ONION               
           TOMATO              
        30 EGG                 
           OIL                 
        40 CHICKEN             
        50 FISH
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually do it in **SQL*Plus** and it is all about **formatting your output**.

You could use **BREAK ON *column_name***.

For example,

```
SQL> break on deptno
SQL> SELECT deptno, ename FROM emp order by deptno;

    DEPTNO ENAME
---------- ----------
        10 CLARK
           KING
           MILLER
        20 JONES
           FORD
           ADAMS
           SMITH
           SCOTT
        30 WARD
           TURNER
           ALLEN
           JAMES
           BLAKE
           MARTIN

14 rows selected.
```

Most of the GUI based client tools now support most of the **`SQL*Plus` commands**. For example, in **SQL Developer**, you could run as script i.e. **F5**. In **PL/SQL Developer**, there is a different window for SQL*Plus like environment. However, if you want pure SQL approach, I suggest @Boneist's solution.

Comment: Yes, it does. If you know how to use a tool. I use SQL*Plus. For any GUI based work, I use SQL Developer. Both are free. https://community.oracle.com/thread/1004607?start=0&tstart=0 AFAIK, TOAD, PL/SQL Developer, SQL Developer, all have "run as script" functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I want to generate one report using sub program for the same output. It's possible to use your code inside the sub program?

Comment: Depends on the sub-program. is it PL/SQL? if you want to SPOOL the output, then simply connect to sqlplus, do the necessary formatting and SPOOL the file.

Comment: Yes it's PL/SQL only. Plan to use cursor and move it to report. 
It this possible?

Comment: PL/SQL is not meant for formatting the output. If you are planning to do so, then bad idea I would say. You could have your PL/SQL give you the desired output, and then use some formatting tool. By report do you mean Oracle Reports?

Answer (score 1):

use below query for u r required o/p

```
select case when rno=1
    then 
    order_id
    else
    null
    end
    as order_id,item
    from
    (
    select order_id,item, row_number() over (partition by order_id order by order_id)  rno from sales
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Use LAG(COLUMN_NAME) OVER (ORDER BY)

LAG(COLUMN_NAME) gets previous record.

```
SELECT DECODE(ORDER_ID, PRE_ORDER_ID, null, ORDER_ID) AS ORDER_ID,
       ITEM
  FROM
    (SELECT ORDER_ID,
            LAG(ORDER_ID) over 
                (order by ORDER_ID) AS PRE_ORDER_ID,
            ITEM
       FROM SALES);
```